# How can I run mogrify, but prefix the filename?

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I have 300k+ jpg files in the same directory. Files are like:

```
/covers    
0788862281217.jpg
0788863155104.jpg
7888311516341.jpg
7888370920479.jpg
7888497074277.jpg
```

I need to batch resize saving the resized images in the **same directory** with a prefix **th_** in filename like

```
th_0788862281217.jpg
th_0788863155104.jpg
th_7888311516341.jpg
th_7888370920479.jpg
th_7888497074277.jpg
```

all inside `/covers`

The following works but it overwrites the source files

```
$ find thumbs -type f -name "*.jpg" | xargs mogrify -resize 75x75
```

so I have to copy all the images into a new dir (/covers/thumbs) and then run the batch and then move all the files back to /covers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the manual:

> Mogrify overwrites the original image file, whereas, convert(1) writes to a different image file.

You can do:

```
find ./covers -type f -name '*.jpg' -execdir convert {} -resize 75x75 th_{} \;
```

This will probably be the most efficient if you have a large number of files.

<sub>In general, [for various reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) it is a rather bad idea to pipe the output of `find` to `xargs`, unless you use the following pattern, which the GNU and BSD `find` variants support: `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`</sub>

---

If you want to use shell-only commands, you can loop over the files like so:

```
for image in ./covers/*.jpg; do convert "$image" -resize 75x75 "$(dirname $image)/th_$(basename $image)"; done
```

That's the easiest (and safest) you can get, without having to resort to external commands. You will, however need to split up path and filename and insert the prefix in between. If you're already in the same folder, this is much easier:

```
for i in *.jpg; do convert "$i" -resize 75x75 "th_$i"; done
```

A universal and shorter solution with Zsh:

```
for i (./covers/*.jpg) convert "$i" -resize 75x75 "${i:h}/th_${i:t}"
```

Comment: hi there! My files are NOT in the /thumbs folder but in /covers. So I assume the command line will become:
for image in covers/*.jpg; do convert "$image" -resize 75x75 "th_$(basename $image)"; done

Will this save in the same dir as the master files?

Correct? Tnx!

Comment: I tried with a sample dir/files. It didn't work

Comment: Sorry, wrong folder there. See my latest update. If you want the command to work with any arbitrary folder, then you need to split up the path between `dirname` and `basename` and insert the prefix there. The following would be easier, if you're already in the folder: `for i in *.jpg; do convert "$i" -resize 75x75 "th_$i"; done`.

Comment: test with 3 images was succesful. I'll run it in the main dir with 300K+ files and I'll get back here. Thanks slhck!

Comment: If your argument list ends up too long (because of 300K+ files), try the variant using `find` with `execdir` which I added to my answer above.

Comment: Ok it worked! This is what I have used...
for i in *.jpg; do convert "$i" -resize 135x135 "sm_$i"; done -------

then I used the "sm_" images and I have resized them down to 75x75 with...------

for i in sm_*.jpg; do convert "$i" -resize 75x75 "th_$i"; done (still in process)