# Using "for in" to iterates files but except specified one(s) in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I found a post here [How can I run mogrify, but prefix the filename?](https://superuser.com/questions/597428/how-can-i-run-mogrify-but-prefix-the-filename) which is talking about resizing a batch of images.

In it there's a `for in` shell script. How do I except some single file(s) while iterate most rest of them.

`for image in *.png; do convert "$image" -resize 29.5% "$(dirname $image)/th_$(basename $image)"; done`

For example:

I have those files in my folder (the don't have any common names like a same prefix):

```
example_1_some_suffix.png
some_prefix_example_2.png
example_3.png
example_4.png
example_a.png
```

I can use `for images in *.png` to iterate all, but what if I want only to do things with the first four files while leave the fifth one out?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on extglob to be able to specify the mask in more detail

```
shopt -s extglob
for image in ?(a)+(b)*.png ; do ...
```

If you just want skip a given file, you can do

```
for image in *.png ; do
    [[ $image == file-to-skip.png ]] && continue
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, but seems not working for the second way. I write it in a single line like: `for image in *.png ; do [[ $image == file-to-skip.png ]] && continue ...` is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have bash version 4:

```
declare -A exceptions=(
    [example_1_some_suffix.png]=skip
    [some_prefix_example_2.png]=skip
    [example_3.png]=skip
    [example_4.png]=skip
    [example_a.png]=skip
)
for image in *.png; do 
    [[ "${exceptions["$image"]}" == skip ]] && continue 
    # ...
```

Without using associative arrays:

```
exceptions=(
    example_1_some_suffix.png 
    some_prefix_example_2.png 
    example_3.png 
    example_4.png 
    example_a.png 
)
for image in *.png; do 
    [[ " ${exceptions[*]} " == *" $image "* ]] && continue 
    # ...
```

All quotes and spaces required.